# Disable "Merge" button in PR until certain conditions are met? (BitBucket Cloud)

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket, pull-request, bitbucket-api

Could somebody hint me if it's possible to disable the "Merge" button in PR **(bitbucket cloud)** until certain conditions are met? Irregardless of whether this would be a setting or even a custom plugin written from the scratch. Any plausible option would do.

**P.S. Basically what I'm looking for the "Merge Checks" functionality substitute which is sadly available for bitbucket premium only.**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try External Merge Check Hook Plugin https://github.com/reconquest/atlassian-external-hooks/wiki/Configuration
Write any script and put in in a hooks directory.
This plugin disabled Merge button if script exit code is different of 0.